# VSTS Package Management: Package Description not showing in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, azure-artifacts

I've started using VSTS Package Management. Created the feed and pushed a package. Everything fine so far as you can see in the picture bellow.
[image]

Then I've updated the Nuget sources in VS 2015 so that it includes my PersonalVSTSFeed. When browsing my personal feed packages in VS 2015, it doesn't show the package description ("Set of general use utility classes" in this case) in the list (see picture below). 
 
[image]

However, if I install the package the description will show up, but only in the **Installed** tab. 
 Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Update: a fix for this issue has been deployed. You should now see descriptions in the VS 2015 NuGet Package Manager extension.

---

This is a current limitation of Package Management. Package descriptions aren't returned in the response to the query that the NuGet Package Manager extension makes, so there's no workaround.

We have work planned in an upcoming sprint to fix this; I'll update this answer when the fix is deployed.